# addEventListener compatibility issue in IE

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I am trying to using this plugin in sharepoint 2010.
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/30/google-nexus-website-menu/

But in IE 8 and older versions, its give me some 'addEventListener' and "queryselector' compatibility issue.

how can I fix this?
I am not core developer :) kindly give me complete reference.

[image]

Comment: You should ask this question to the developers of the plug-in, it is hard to tell if your problems are SharePoint related at all

Comment: unfortunately, site closed comments on this code.
I am trying to call 'Quick Launch' in same format, that y I asked over here.

Comment: If you are not comfortable with modifying the code you will most likely not have success here with IE8 or lower.  You will probably need to add a polyfill as it looks like you are hitting some things that IE8 does not support.  You will find it painful using IE8 with a lot of "cool" stuff out there now as it just doesn't support the newer ECMA5 and CSS3 standards. You may have better luck posting this on StackOverflow as a general programming questions as its not directly SP related.